# How to display the previously assigned value in a variable in PHP?

Tags: php

I have some PHP statements as

```
<?php 
$i = 10;
$i = 15;
echo $i;
?>
```

Now we all are aware of the fact that this will give us "15", what should i do after assignment to the variable $i with value "15", so that we can get output as "10"?

Comment: No third variable shld b involved

Comment: Yeah, use a SECOND variable, not a THIRD :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Once a variable has been reassigned its previous value is lost.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't specific to PHP. When ever you have a list of statements like that that assign values to a variable, the variable will have the value set by the last statement to execute.

Comment: To be fair, it is possible to have a language maintain a list of revisions to a variable, and then to access the revisions in code. But PHP is not a language that does so.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot achieve that. But you might do this.

```
$i[] = 10;
$i[] = 15;
```

If you assign as above, you will get the following:-

```
echo $i[0]  // will give 10
echo $i[1]  // will give 15
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use array otherwise no way.